# How to disable SSL connections in WSO2 APIM and IS on Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, wso2, ssl-certificate

I want to deploy wso2 apim and is (as km) on kubernetes.
I have deployed them via helm chart on a minikube with self-signed ssl for internal and for the client side (via ingress) communications.
I want to deploy them on a staging kubernetes, I want to test offloading client-side SSL. How can I set it up?

The domain has a valid certificate, but I haven't have the certs or a signed cert to import to ingress or insert to the truststore of wso2 pods and actually I don't want it at all. I want to disable all ssl connections or at least ssl connections which come from domain and ingress.

Comment: So what does [tag:ssl-certificate] have to do with it?

Comment: For API Manager GW calls you can use the Non-SSL port and for others, you can't avoid SSL.